# Ruby on Rails 5 - CoffeeScript no funciona

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Estoy batallando con el uso de Javascript en Rails, en específico con CoffeeScript que no me lo carga en la aplicación; en ningún tutorial de internet he visto de manera clara cómo programar los eventos, solo he leído que se maneja distinto por *turbolinks*.

Tengo un controlador de prueba `brands` y ya edité el archivo *brands.coffee* con el siguiente código, pero no me funciona; supuestamente con eso compruebas al cargar la página:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```

Luego agregué un botón a la vista y buscando encontré un código y lo adapte así, y tampoco me carga:

```
$ ->
  $("#boton").on "click", ->
    alert "hiciste click"
```

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error en la consola de rails o en la del navegador (la puedes ver a través de las herramientas de desarrollador en tu navegador)?

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias... faltaba un //= require_tree .

Comment: estas llamando el archivo brands.coffee en tu app.js de rails?, Saludos